# How to cascade delete grand children table entities if they have a reference to foreign key of parent and primary key of grand parent

Tags: java, mysql

I have table relation like this `scenario -> event -> plan` and they are:

scenario_table:

```
 CREATE TABLE `scenario` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `plan_cycle_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_by` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `scenario_table_plan_cycle_id_fk` (`plan_cycle_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `scenario_table_plan_cycle_id_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`plan_cycle_id`) REFERENCES `planning_cycle` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

event_table

```
CREATE TABLE `event` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `start_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `end_date` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `scenario_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `created_by` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_scenario_id` (`scenario_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_scenario_id` FOREIGN KEY (`scenario_id`) REFERENCES `scenario` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

plan_table

```
CREATE TABLE `plan` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `scenario_id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `input` json DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `updated_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `created_by` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `plan_scenario_id` (`scenario_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKnjhfw18pms9j2yhtvu954hcsi` FOREIGN KEY (`scenario_id`) REFERENCES `scenario` (`id`), // this was not there in create table command but later added by mysql //
  CONSTRAINT `plan_scenario_id` FOREIGN KEY (`scenario_id`) REFERENCES `event` (`scenario_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Now I want to cascade delete scenario, event and plan for some particular scenario_id. When there are no grandchildren, scenario and event are getting deleter as expected. But when a new entry is present in plan which refers a scenario_id, am getting this error while deletion:

```
java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`db_dev`.`plan`, CONSTRAINT `plan_scenario_id` FOREIGN KEY (`scenario_id`) REFERENCES `event` (`scenario_id`))
```

I tried EAGER loading in eventEntity.java like this:

```
@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "scenario", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private List<planEntity> planEntityList;
```

and in planEntity.java like this:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "scenario_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private ScenarioEntity scenario;
```

How I can handle this case through *entity.java files ?

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server - please correct your tags.

Answer (score 0):

In MySql when a table is InnoDB you can Add **Foreign Key Constraints**. Foreign Key checks is done when you update or delete a record. The results of foreign Key checks depend on the design of your table as you may allow cascading the update or delete or prevent the process of update or delete.
The following is an example of a parent:

```
CREATE TABLE parent (
    id INT NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Example of child table that allows parent table to delete or update the (id) field of the parent table (Child also will be deleted):

```
CREATE TABLE child (
    id INT,
    parent_id INT,
    INDEX par_ind (parent_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id)
        REFERENCES parent(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Example of child table that prevents the update of (id) field of parent but allows parent table to be deleted. (Child also will be deleted):

```
CREATE TABLE child (
    id INT,
    parent_id INT,
    INDEX par_ind (parent_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id)
        REFERENCES parent(id)
        ON DELETE CASCADE 
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

Example of child table that prevents parent table to delete or update the (id) field of the parent table. This will give error like "Cannot Delete or Update a Parent Row: A Foreign Key Constraint Fails":

```
CREATE TABLE child (
    id INT,
    parent_id INT,
    INDEX par_ind (parent_id),
    FOREIGN KEY (parent_id)
        REFERENCES parent(id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

You have four options when using foreign key constraints :

> RESTRICT | CASCADE | SET NULL | NO ACTION | SET DEFAULT

RESTRICT : is the default if you don't include ON UPDATE/ON DELETE
CASCADE  : Delete child when delete parent or update parent_id when id of parent changed.
for more information you can see [FOREIGN KEY Constraints](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)

There is also a variable that control foreign key checks. If you set it to 0 (false) you will disable foreign key checks.

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

Back to your database, I think it is better to modify your tables structure to allow cascade delete. You can also use `ON DELETE SET NULL` then later you can delete any record where parent_id=null. If you can't modify tables structure then you have to first delete records in child table before deleting parent record.

Comment: Thanks @Ehab for detailed explanation. Unfortunately, here I can't modify tables. But as I said, I'm able to delete parent & child both with CASCADE.ALL with `@OneToMany`,  `@ManyToOne` annotations without grand child (without change in tables). 
Problem is, when grand child entry is created with those references mentioned it is not allowing.

Comment: Then you will do it the hard way. You will delete child first  then parent and finally the grandparent. I wish you good luck.